# ¿Cómo volcar el valor de una columna existencia en mi columna pivoteada?

Tags: sql-server

**Tengo esta consulta que selecciona datos de una tabla y convierte los nombres de lineas y grupos a columnas lo que quiero lograr es agregarle una columna mas Existencia y ademas volcar ese valor dentro de las nuevas columnas pivoteadas la base de datos que uso es sql server 2012, actualmente no está volcando los valores de la columna existencia a las columnas pivoteadas ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME('Descripcion_linea'+''+[Descripcion_linea] + '_' + 'Descripcion_Grupo'+''+[Descripcion_grupo])
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT [Cod_linea], [Descripcion_linea], [Grupo], [Descripcion_grupo]
                FROM v_sc_stockpivot
            ) subquery
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 'SELECT Empresa, Sucursal, [Codigo_deposito], [Descripcion_deposito], [Descripcion_linea], [Descripcion_grupo], Articulo,Existencia ' + @cols + ' 
              FROM 
              (
                  SELECT Empresa, Sucursal, [Cod_linea], [Descripcion_linea], [Grupo], [Descripcion_grupo], Articulo, [Codigo_deposito], [Descripcion_deposito], 
                         [Descripcion_linea] + ''_'' + [Descripcion_grupo] AS DescLinea_Grupo, 
                         COALESCE(SUM(Valor), 0) AS Valor

                  FROM
                  (
                      SELECT Empresa, Sucursal, [Cod_linea], [Grupo], Articulo, [Codigo_deposito], [Descripcion_deposito], Existencia, Comprometido,
                             [Descripcion_linea], [Descripcion_grupo]
                      FROM v_sc_stockpivot
                      WHERE [Codigo_deposito] = 5 AND Sucursal = 0
                  ) x
                  UNPIVOT
                  (
                      Valor
                      FOR ColumnaValor IN (Existencia, Comprometido)
                  ) u
                  GROUP BY Empresa, Sucursal, [Cod_linea], [Descripcion_linea], [Grupo], [Descripcion_grupo], Articulo, [Codigo_deposito], [Descripcion_deposito], [Descripcion_linea] + ''_'' + [Descripcion_grupo]
              ) x
              PIVOT 
              (
                  SUM(Valor)
                  FOR DescLinea_Grupo IN (' + @cols + ')
              ) p';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

**La estructura de la vista de donde consulto los datos v_sc_stockpivot es la siguiente**

```html
ALTER view  [dbo].[v_sc_stockpivot]

as 
SELECT  s.[Empresa],
    s.[Sucursal],
    SUC.[Nombre sucursal] as Nombre_Sucursal,
    s.[Codigo deposito] as Codigo_deposito,
    sd.[Descripcion deposito] as Descripcion_deposito,
    a.[Articulo],
    a.[Descripcion articulo] as Descripcion_articulo,
    a.[Cod linea] AS Cod_linea,
    l.[Descripcion linea] as Descripcion_linea,
    a.Grupo,
    g.[Descripcion grupo] as Descripcion_grupo,
    s.[Existencia],
    s.[Comprometido],
    s.[Existencia] as Existencia1
FROM STOCK S 
inner join Sucursal suc on suc.Empresa=S.Empresa AND SUC.Sucursal=S.Sucursal
INNER JOIN [Sucursal deposito] SD ON S.Empresa=SD.Empresa and s.Sucursal=sd.Sucursal  and S.[Codigo deposito]=SD.[Codigo deposito] 
inner join articulos a
        on s.Empresa = a.empresa and s.Articulo = a.Articulo 
Inner join Linea l on a.Empresa=l.Empresa and l.[Cod linea]=a.[Cod linea]
inner join Grupos g on a.Empresa=g.Empresa and g.[Cod linea]=l.[Cod linea] and g.Grupo=a.Grupo
where s.empresa = 1 and sd.Activo=0 and 
          a.Activo = 0 and a."Administra lotes" = 0
```

**El resultado que debería devolver mi consulta pivot  seria este**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir datos de ejemplo en forma de código y el resultado que se debe obtener de esos datos?

Comment: ahora incluí los resultados que debería devolver, no esta cargando los totales de la existencia en las columnas pívot como se puede ver están nulos